# Why are there different outputs for 'while' loop depending on postion of 'print' statement?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to Python and I encountered this problem using `while` loops. Depending on where the `print` statement is located (after 'while' or at end of loop) I get 2 different outputs.

```
# 'While' loop example with 'print' after 'while' statement
i = 2
x = 10
while i < x: # Perform loop until this condition no longer true: i is less than x
    print(i) # Print output of loop iteration
    i = i + 2 # Loop to perform: add 2 to i
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
8
```

```
# 'While' loop example with 'print' at end of loop
i = 2
x = 10
while i < x: # Perform loop until this condition no longer true: i is less than x
    i = i + 2 # Loop to perform: add 2 to i  
    print(i) # Print output of loop iteration
```

Output:

```
4
6
8
10
```

I thought the output would be the same. How is Python reading the loops in each case?
Also this is the first time I have posted here, so if I am not following the correct format please let me know.

Comment: Python is an imperative language. The order of statements affects the program.

Comment: "Print output of loop iteration" is a misleading comment. `print(I)` prints the value of the variable `i`. Why is it surprising that adding to `i` before printing it will print a different value?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reproduce it by yourself, with a pencil on a blank paper. 
First case:

- At first `i` is equal to 2, so `print(i)` will print 2, then increment it by 2, now `i` is equal to 4
- Then printing `i` will print 4, then you add 2, so now `i` is equal to 6...
- When `i = i+2` changes the value of `i` to 10, at the next iteration `i < x` is false, so you exit the loop.

Second case:

- At first `i` is equal to 2, but you add immediately 2, so `i` is equal to 4 and then you print it
- Then you add 2, so now `i` is equal to 6 and you print it...
- When `i = i+2` changes the value of `i` to 10, you print it last time and at the next iteration `i < x` is false, so you exit the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I understand that the statement order makes a difference now.